# Maven Deploy : How to get snapsnot version

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a way to capture the actual snapshot version and let's say output it to file?

```
[INFO] Uploading to nexus: https://xxxx/repository/xxx/xxx/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/xxx-0.0.1-2
0180809.182425-2.pom
```

I can see it in the console output, but I am looking for a reliable way to extract it and use it for some post processing, by example, assemble it in a docker image and deploy it.

Comment: To put that into a docker image you could use https://dmp.fabric8.io/ ... for recording it: https://github.com/khmarbaise/deployment-recorder-extension ?

Comment: You could also consider https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin as an alternative way of recording what produced the image. It may be worth thinking about how long your nexus keeps snapshots for and whether you could link back from snapshot to source code.

Answer (score 0):

As khmarbaise suggests, you could get the snapshot info from a Maven extension such as https://github.com/khmarbaise/deployment-recorder-extension  Recording a timestamp would also give you a good approximation as normally snapshot ids are timestamp-based.

It is worth being cautious about how much value you put on the snapshot for traceability as snapshots are typically not retained in nexus indefinitely. If you're looking to trace the code in a docker image that is itself using a latest/snapshot tag then you might find more value in the last git commit (https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin). If the image will have its own dedicated tag then it would be advisable to also create a corresponding tag in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to achieve during the build process as the deploy-plugin uses the very timestamp of the deployment to version the artifact and it will not share that information other than in the log. That means that any timestamp that you catch during the build process will be before that timstamp and will therefore not be suitable.

To solve the issue, you either need to parse the command output or use external tools:

- Use khmarbais's [Deployment recorder](https://github.com/khmarbaise/deployment-recorder-extension) (as mentioned by @Ryan Dawson)
- Read the `maven-metadata` from Nexus which contains the latest snapshot info
- Search whether Nexus has an api that exposes that information (I am using Artifactory and am therefore not an expert for Nexus)